# Proper title capitalization of parenthesis

Tags: capitalization, titles

How should Capitalizing for example "Exit Music (for a Film)"? Usually in a title the parenthetical phrase serves as subtitle, but in this case it is evidently a continuation, accordingly "for" should be capitalized or not?

Thanks.

Comment: That example is from a music album, and the rules tend to go out the window when it comes to album covers. Also, that example is not a valid sentence, so trying to apply grammar rules to it is going to be tricky.

Comment: What would make "for" capitalized depending on whether it was a subtitle or not? And what makes a parenthetical phrase a subtitle rather than a continuation of the main title? Capitalization of titles depends entirely on the style to which you wish to adhere.

Answer (score -1):

Mixing of formats (parenthesis within a title here - which I'd say is very unusual) can lead to a conflict of 'accepted rules' (for which one should almost always read guidelines). Would

> Film Exit Music

not work?

There seems to be generally far greater freedom allowed for assembling and punctuating strings within parentheses than for the matrix sentence (or here, matrix sentence-substitute). I've never seen a 'rule' demanding that one must not capitalise the same way as one does in the non-parenthetical material, so I'd not say that your punctuation is wrong. For such a peripheral question, it's unlikely you'll find a single style guide giving any guidance. If you by some miracle find two, the odds are they'll disagree. I *do* find this five-word title clumsy, however.

Since it's relevant, I'll point out that, in your first line, 'capitalizing' should not be capitalised. That string is also ungrammatical.

Comment: If *"Exit Music (for a Film)"* works better than *"Film Exit Music"* — and I think it does — you should not let the question of how to capitalize it keep you from using it.